# C# Unity Queue NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a simple dialogue system for my game in Unity. I've set up a special trigger for a Dialogue to start and the code is passing right variable but somehow it gets stuck at clearing the queue and throws a `NullReferenceException`.

I've seen through debugger that all variables and triggers work perfectly fine till cs:27 inside `DialogueManager.cs`. I've also checked the inspector to make sure everything is correctly assigned.

**Dialogue** class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public string name;

    [TextArea(3,10)]
     public string[] sentences;
}
```

**DialogueTrigger** class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPC_DialogTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Player
    public Transform player;

    // GameMaager to close
    public GameObject Gameplay;

    // Camera and Canvas to turn on
    public GameObject DialogueManager;

    // NPC Details
    public GameObject InteractionNPCNameTextField;
    public Transform interactionTransform;
    public float radius = 3f;
    private bool isBusy = false;

    // DialogueStart
    public GameObject DialogueStart;

    void Start()
    {
        InteractionNPCNameTextField.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
         float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, interactionTransform.position);

         if (distance <= radius)
         {
              if (isBusy == false)
              {
                   InteractionNPCNameTextField.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                   {
                        Dialogue();
                        Debug.Log("Started Dialogue procedure.");
                   }
              }
         }
         else if (distance > radius)
         {
             InteractionNPCNameTextField.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
    }

    public void Dialogue()
    {
        Gameplay.SetActive(false);
        DialogueManager.SetActive(true);
        DialogueStart.GetComponent<DialogueStart>().TriggerDialogue();
        Debug.Log("Triggered Dialogue.");
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (interactionTransform == null)
        {
            interactionTransform = transform;
        }

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(interactionTransform.position, radius);
    }
}
```

**DialogueStart** class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueStart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
         Debug.Log("Dialogue sent to dialogue manager.");
    }
}
```

**DialogueManager** class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text nameText;
    public Text DialogueText;

    private Queue<string> sentences;
    public GameObject DialogueManagerUI;

    void Start()
    {
        if (sentences == null)
        {
             sentences = new Queue<string>();
        }
    }

    public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        Debug.Log("Received dialogues: " + dialogue);
        nameText.text = dialogue.name;
        Debug.Log("Start Dialogue: " + sentences.Count);
        sentences.Clear();
        Debug.Log("Sentences Cleared: " + sentences);

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
             sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if(sentences.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
        DialogueText.text = sentence;
    }

    void EndDialogue()
    {
        Debug.Log("End of conversation.");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (DialogueManagerUI.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
        else if (!DialogueManagerUI.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio doesn't give me any errors.

Unity error code -> [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/rfl8ah)

Debugger right before issue -> [Screenshot2](https://prnt.sc/rfl920)

Seems to me like the Queue is never assigned to sentences and it remains empty. 
If it is so - why?

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could provide a [minimal reproducible error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Secondly, just a thought, why not instantiate the list just on your variable declaration? Just to test.

Comment: I think your `Start` function does not fired, have you tried to put the `Debug.Log` on the top of the `Start` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `DialogueManager.StartDialogue` probably via `DialogueStart.TriggerDialogue` is called from somewhere in either `Awake` or at least before your `Start` was executed.

Especially

```
DialogueManager.SetActive(true);
```

lets assume the `DialogueManager` object is inactive at first anyway. So maybe your stuff is called before it is set to active.

This might also be due to the `Start` where you set

```
InteractionNPCNameTextField.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

so any component on this `GameObject` might not have its `Start` method getting called. Maybe you referenced the wrong `GameObject` here?

[Debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) would help to figure out in which order your methods get called.

In general my thumb rule for initializing is

- Do everything that depends only on yourself in `Awake`
- Do everything that depends on other components being setup already in `Start`

This way you can (almost) always be sure that stuff is already initialized when you need it.

---

However, these are only guesses but

#### The simple solution here:

You could already solve this by simply initializing the `sentences` right away using

```
private readonly Queue<string> sentences = new Queue<string>();
```

now it is definitely initialized even before `Start` or `Awake` get called!

Comment: Thank you! I am so greatfull for such a descriptive analysis and solution. I don't quite know why this Start() is not activating even tho i am triggering the rest of the code way after starting the actual game, but your solution with initializing the sentences worked!